# Active zabbix agents are becoming unavailable due to DHCP IP change

Tags: monitoring, agent, zabbix, dhcp

I am using active Zabbix agents that auto-register themselves to the Zabbix server.
Everything goes well until the DHCP changes the host IP, the host then becomes unavailable in Zabbix... Looking at the host under the hosts list in Zabbix frontend, I can see that it had the old IP. 
Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This means that you are actually not using active items. I'd suggest cloning your current template and changing items, LLD rules and LLD prototypes to "Zabbix agent (active)" - then agent IP address changes will not be a concern.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.